# NullPointerException error on trying to cast row's custom view

Tags: java, android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, android-custom-view

On a fragment I got this:

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) 
{
     CommentItem rowView = (CommentItem) list.getChildAt(firstVisibleItem);
     rowView.hola();
}
```

Each listview row is a custom view called `CommentItem`, and I'm casting the row to this custom view. What I want is calling the method `hola()`, but I got the following error:

```
06-11 19:28:27.418: E/AndroidRuntime(12133): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-11 19:28:27.418: E/AndroidRuntime(12133):    at com.devyanlab.qoment.fragments.CommentsFragment.onScroll(CommentsFragment.java:243)
```

The line 243 `rowView.hola();`;

I don't know for sure if that is the right way to get the row's view.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The answer is obvious: rowView is null.  Why would that be?  Because getChildAt(firstVisibleItem) returned null.  Why would that happen?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is get the visible current row as I scroll, and call `hola()`. What can I do to avoid getting `null`?

Comment: Sorry, the line is 243.

Comment: I've should ask: "How can I get the current visible row as I scroll?". Once I get the row, I can cast it to my custom view and then call the method. Right?

Comment: rowView is not null. Doing a logcat, I get this:
`06-11 20:00:00.302: I/---qoment---(14663): row: com.company.myapp.components.CommentItem{532825a4 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-720,852 #7f060089 app:id/wrapper}
`

Comment: If I execute this code:
`CommentItem rowView = (CommentItem) list.getChildAt(0);
     rowView.hola();` outside `onScroll`, let's say on `onCreateView`, `hola()` gets called, and everything works as expected. I think the problem relies on `firstVisibleItem` variable not being the current visible row index.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code behind getChildAt, you'll see this

```
public View getChildAt(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= mChildrenCount) {
        return null;
    }
    return mChildren[index];
}
```

Now this has absolutely no relation to ListView.

There should be no reason for you to have to get the `View` behind a row in the scroll method, you should be using your `Adapter` and getView method for that.